# SVG not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

My CSS-animated SVG does not seem to appear in Mozilla Firefox 58, but it does in Chrome.

[image: view in chrome]

Here is a link to the codepen page: https://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/qXvWxo

Why does this happen? Removing `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` does not seem to help.

Comment: Firefox 57.0 here and I see it.

Comment: @Kangouroops OP has modified the linked codepen.

Comment: @Stijn Oh, I hadn't seen the edit. sorry.

Comment: @Kangouroops No worries, there doesn't seem to be an indication on codepen that it was modified, so you can only know if you saw the original version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your circle's cx/cy/r css styles to element attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use CSS to target SVG attributes, at least not with SVG 1.1. It's supposed to be possible with SVG 2.0, but browser support is very limited currently.