# Styling of SVG circle doesn´t work in Firefox, browser removes radius property

Tags: html, css, angular, firefox, svg

I'm trying to create a kind of progress ring with an SVG and CSS, which worked so far in Chrome. However, Firefox (61.0.1 (64-bit)) causes me problems and doesn't show my circle. I have already tried to use the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866893/svg-fill-not-being-applied-in-firefox), but without success. Is there a way to style the ring to display correctly in both Chrome and Firefox (both in the latest version)? Is it problematic, that I add styles with `[ngStyles]` during runtime? this is needed to calculate the space and the shown progress

I have a running [example on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lyz3ywoml9) for you, which also just is working for chrome, but not for Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-progress-ring">
    <svg>
        <circle class="progress" [ngStyle]="getCircleStyles()"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.my-progress-ring {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

circle.progress {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

**Typescript**

```
public getCircleStyles(): any {
    return {
      'r': 21,
      'stroke-dasharray': 131.947,
      'stroke-dashoffset': 32.987
    };
  }
```

---

**EDIT:**
The numbers for the getCircleStyles are hardcoded in this example. In my app i´m using a function to calculate the numbers depending on the size of the progress ring and the current progress.

**EDIT 2:**
It seems that Firefox doesn't like some properties of values of my stlying. The r property is missing
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you found an inconsistent implementation of [the SVG 2.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#StylingUsingCSS) in Firefox. Or, maybe Firefox does not fully support SVG 2.0 yet. The specification states that:

> Some styling properties can be specified not only in style sheets and ‘style’ attributes, but also in presentation attributes.

So, both style sheets and attributes should work.

---

The quick fix is to add `r`, `cx`and `cy` **presentation attributes** to your `circle` element ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47381187/svg-not-working-in-firefox)):

```
<circle _ngcontent-c1="" class="progress" style="stroke-dasharray: 131.947; stroke-dashoffset: 32.987;" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="21" fill="transparent" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></circle>
```

Comment: Good idea, by using `[attr.cx]`, `[attr.cy]` and `[attr.r]` I´m also able to set these variables dynamically using typescript

Comment: Are there any ployfills to enable firefox to work with the latest implementation of SVG2?

Comment: @JohnDizzle I don't know if this can be fixed with a polyfill. Also, since chrome supports the presentation attributes `cx`, `cy` and `r` you should fallback to using those attributes everywhere. That's way simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I just have noticed, that one has to add units (`px`) to make `r`, `x`, `y` work in Firefox v. 102:

```
.ring
{
    r: 150px; /* r: 150; not working */
}
```

Fortunately, units work in both Chrome and Firefox.

It's interesting, that the following rules work with no units:

```
.ring
{
    cx: calc(var(--svg-width) / 2);
    cy: calc(var(--svg-height) / 2); /* calc() works with no 'px' */
    stroke-width: 5; /* stroke-width works too. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@JohnDizzle, while Chrome has supported circle's css `r` attribute for a long while, I noticed my most recent version of Firefox 74.0b8 on Mac, now does as well.

Also, Safari 13.0.5 supports css `r`, although I don't recall if it did not do so in the past.

Answer (score 0):

We used to need to use attributes for cx, cy, r if you wanted it to work anywhere other than Chrome but now Safari and Firefox have caught up and your code should work in all those browsers.

Having cx, cy and r as styles is a new feature of the SVG 2 specification. Many attributes are now mapped CSS properties instead.

Comment: Are there any ployfills to enable firefox to work with the latest implementation of SVG2?

Comment: SVG 2 has many changes, Firefox has implemented some parts, Chrome other parts, Edge and Safari have implemented bits too. There's some overlap but it's a complete mismash of stuff amongst the browsers. There's no uber polyfill to ensure consistency.